# C# return type inference bad practice?

Tags: c#

Is this way to force C# to use return type inference a really bad practice????

So I have an interface like this:

```
public interface IQueryHandlerRunner
{
    TResult RunHandler<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query)
        where TQuery : IQuery;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
_queryHandlerRunner.RunHandler<GiveMeAllPreferedCustomersQuery, PreferedCustomersDto[]>(
    new GiveMeAllPreferedCustomersQuery());
```

But I'd like to be able to use return type inference but I know that can't be done....

Well it can actually, so I created an overload like this one:

```
TResult RunHandler<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query, TResult result)
    where TQuery : IQuery;
```

And I use it like this:

```
_queryHandlerRunner.RunHandler(new GiveMeAllPreferedCustomersQuery(), default(PreferedCustomersDto[]));
```

It feels a cleaner approach but at the same time it feels dirty lol like a smell

What do you think

I don't like the fact that I'm introducing the return type as a parameter in my API but the calls to my api look better and easier to read

Am I going crazy here? Or should I just stop smoking for today....I'm confused

Comment: http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/partial-type-inference-in-net.html

Comment: If you're doing it because you actually want to be able to specify a default return value, then it's fine. If you're just doing it so you don't have to type out those `<bracketed, arguments>`, then it's not really (subjectively, anyway).

Comment: @valverij Note that when anonymous types are involved type inference isn't just a convenience, it's a requirement.

Comment: @Servy, good call, I didn't event think about anonymous types here

Answer (score 1):

I use this pattern regularly for both reducing verbosity and for supporting anonymous types. Usually, I'll declare the method as follows:

```
TResult Run<TQuery, TResult>(TQuery query, TResult schema = default(TResult));
```

When calling, I always name the schema argument (e. g. `schema: new { a = default(int) }`), which I find makes the code a lot less smelly than just passing a random default or anonymous type. Also, by setting a default fr the argument I make it possible to leave out the extra argument in case you want to specify the type arguments manually (which you may at times want to do when anonymous types aren't involved).

Most importantly, I've found that other developers I work with who are less familiar with the intricacies of type inference and generics don't struggle to read or use these methods; they're able to understand the intent and follow the pattern in their own code.